# How do I add ios folder to an Existing Flutter Project?

Tags: flutter

I delete the ios folder in my existing flutter project and I want to recreate the ios folder from mac book but it's not working I tried with the following

flutter create --platforms=ios
flutter create
flutter create -i swift
all these command not working it gives me
Run Flutter help to see gloabl options
any idea how to recreate the ios folder for existing projects
thanks

Comment: Does anything here help? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110072

Comment: Make sure you add `[space]dot` at the end of the command like this `flutter create --platforms=ios .`

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak
I run flutter create --platforms=ios .
but it gives me "Project Name" is not a valid Dart package name.

Comment: What is your project name in the `pubspec.yaml`? The project name should be `lower_case_with_underscores`

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak
the "Project Name" is store-master and the name in pubspec.yaml is store and when I run 
run flutter create --platforms=ios .
it gives me "store-master"  is not a valid Dart package name.

Comment: you need to change store-master to store_master and clean the project.